# Вызов Java сервлета при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, servlet

Возможно ли из jsp файла при нажатии на ссылку вызвать метод из сервлета, если да то как?

Comment: Для того, чтобы выполнить это на текущей странице нужно отправить HTTP запрос используя JavaScript (XMLHttpRequest или fetch()).

Comment: Но сделать скриншот сервлет не сможет (он выполняется на сервере). Это нужно делать используя javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Вам в ссылку нужно записать url к сервлету: то, что прописано в `<url-pattern>` теге для этого сервлета.

Comment: При нажатии на ссылку переходит на новый адрес. Нужно чтобы сервлет выполнялся на текущей странице (сервлет делает скриншот и сохраняет на пк).

Comment: В вопросе нужно указывать все условия. Этот вопрос относится больше к `anchor` элементу, а не к jsp/сервлетам. По большому счёту без редиректа, используя только `<a>`, сделать не получиться, нужен JS. Тут полно таких тем, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224920/alternative-to-a-href-when-the-anchor-tag-only-triggers-a-jquery-action-wi/17666326)